# Salesforce Chatter profile pictures restrictions

Tags: salesforce-chatter

is it possible to restrict access to the Chatter profile pictures such that only system administrators can upload photos, and all others are restricted?

Answer (score 1):

Normally field security in an object would help us, but that doesn't exist for `User`. Fundamentally, every user is given control over his or her own profile, including picture, and there aren't field permissions for the user object. You can't modify other users, but you can modify your own.

I struggle to see why you would want to do this, as putting the burden of uploading a photo on the admin seems like busy work that would take away from them doing something more productive. But let's go with it.

Some backstory: The URL for the photo is contained in two `User` object fields: `FullPhotoURL` and `SmallPhotoURL`.

When a `User` record is first created, they are assigned the default blue smiley profile photo that looks like this:

[image: Generic Salesforce Blue Smiley Profile Avatar]

The url for the default photos are always as follows:

- `FullPhotoURL`: `https://c.eu5.content.force.com/profilephoto/005/F`
- `SmallPhotoURL`: `https://c.eu5.content.force.com/profilephoto/005/T`

If I update from the default to a new photo, the `FullPhotoURL` value would look like this: `https://c.eu5.content.force.com/profilephoto/72924000000CisD/F`

And each time it is updated, the record id value above of `72924000000CisD` would be updated to a new one.

The normal fallback position in this case would be to have a trigger look for the modification to the field value and then stop the transaction, thus preventing the user from updating their photo.

However the profile photo upload process does not appear to cause a trigger to fire in my testing.

So the next option you have is to have a batch process that runs on a schedule. Unfortunately this leaves you with having to track the old values of every user's photo somewhere. So the high level steps for this workaround seem to be:

- Add a custom field to user to store the current profile photo url
- Use a one-off batch Apex process, or some kind of data tool like data loader to populate this for existing users, create a workflow rule with a field update to populate it for new user records.
- Periodically run a scheduled apex job to look for users with modified values in their profile photo fields
- When you find those users, either flag it up, or revert to previous value.

Not pretty, but it will put in place the control you want.

From there, you'll need to educate users that they need to expect this to happen.

Comment: How can you confirm that the default photos are _always_ `/profilephoto/005/F` and `/profilephoto/005/T`? I have been trying to confirm that this is definitely the case, but want to be able to confirm it before relying on it.

Comment: I'm basing this purely on the value that is written to that field by default when a new user is created. Could this ever change? Yes. Is it likely to? No. More likely is R&D might change the actual image in the future. But were they to change the actual default field value it would be a breaking action for all existing users still using the old default value. It is doubtful this would ever occur.